# Android slider without overlay

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is there a way to implement `NavigationDrawer` where the navigation menu (the panel that slides in) pushes the main content to right instead of overlaying it?

The default implementation of `NavigationDrawer` overlays (as seen in Google's apps on android), but instead is there a way to prevent the overlay and push the main content to the right as the navigation menu slides out? (like android's facebook app)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move main content with Drawer Layout left side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057084/how-to-move-main-content-with-drawer-layout-left-side)

Comment: Note that the overlay approach is what the design guide recommends.

Comment: ah!! it seems i didn't use the correct search terms!! thank you