# Using ActionBarDrawerToggle makes actionbar not show home icon in right postition

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, title

I need to create a slide menu for my app. So I search and follow the tutorials at [this link](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html). And to make the main content slide from left to right along with the slide menu, I following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057084/how-to-move-main-content-with-drawer-layout-left-side). But I got the result like below:

[image]

I dont know why the menu icon is not on the left side of action bar. Even when I slide the menu to the right or not, It just stay there, just pushes the Application icon and the title to the right, even out of the action bar. I tried to resize the menu icon to very small but It does not work. Please help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: Post some code! Without a code is it difficult to say what is wrong.

Comment: OK, I don't know why but I found the wrong point. Although this is may very weird, the reason is my icon size. I just though if the icon can be fit the height of the action bar then there is no problem whith its width. But when I change my icon from (256px x 256px) to (72px x 72px), the problem is solved. Anyone know why? Please help me explain this.