# Drawerlayout let content slide

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

Is it possible to let the content slide away over the menu instead of letting the menu slide over the content with the standaard drawerlayout from android?

[image]

Or should I better use following library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu for getting something like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057084/how-to-move-main-content-with-drawer-layout-left-side. check this

Comment: try this https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. This library is the best example of doing so.

Comment: Have you tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html
This is android widget (got in support v4 library)