# Moving the main content to reveal a drawer

Tags: android

I'd like to create a navigation drawer effect, but rather than the drawer sliding out from the left, it must be "behind" the main view, so the item that slides is the view itself (i.e. to the right) - the drawer doesn't move at all, but is "revealed" by sliding the main view out of the way. The finger swipe (and tap on hamburger icon) action is the same as with the drawer, just the reveal effect is different.

The way the main view moves is the same to what can be achieved here

[How to move main content with Drawer Layout left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057084/how-to-move-main-content-with-drawer-layout-left-side)

but in my case I want the "drawer" to stay statically underneath the main view.

I've achieved the desired effect by overlaying views and making the drawer transparent - of course this means that the drawer is no longer used for navigation; just for effect. Using the code in the above link

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/whole_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- everything here is now the new "drawer" -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="BOO I am hiding!"
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
<!-- /everything here is now the new "drawer" -->

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<!-- The This is the main content frame -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="MOOOOOO!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
</FrameLayout>


<!-- The see-through navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_bg" <!-- #00FFFFFF -->
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Everything is perfect except that id/tv2 (or other items on that layer) are not clickable when the "drawer" is opened.

I've tried:

1)
Making the layouts above not clickable (drawer_layout, content_frame and left_drawer setClickable(false) without effect).

2)
The code in the above link moves the content_frame on X axis and not the drawyer_layout - I tried moving drawer_layout instead of the frame - this doesn't work properly as you can no longer click on the far right to close the drawer again.

3)
Changing the android:layout_width of the drawer_layout to fill_parent, but this is still a problem as it is not the layer being moved out of the way.

My guess is that DrawerLayout ( android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ) is not meant to be above another layout and I might need to create my own drawer to achieve the desired effect - any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I've figured out a relatively simple solution. The following `DrawerLayout` setup is pretty standard - i.e., the content `ViewGroup` first, the drawer `View` last, using standard attributes, etc. Additionally, a technique similar to that shown in your posted link is used to slide the content with the drawer.

The trick in the example is the setup of the drawer itself. We're going to use two nested `ViewGroup`s - the outer one is the regular sliding drawer `View`; the inner, a `ViewGroup` for the actual drawer contents. We'll then slide the inner content `ViewGroup` opposite the direction of the drawer's slide using a `DrawerListener` (an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in our example), making the drawer appear static against the left side.

The example `DrawerLayout`, `main.xml`. Note the standard drawer attributes set on the `drawer_container` `ViewGroup`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            ...

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This example `Activity` shows the few extra lines we need to add to a regular Navigation Drawer setup. Other than getting references to the `View`s, the main bit is in the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`'s `onDrawerSlide()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    View drawerContainer;
    View drawerContent;
    View mainContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerContainer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_container);
        drawerContent = findViewById(R.id.drawer_content);
        mainContent = findViewById(R.id.main_content);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawer, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawer, slideOffset);

                drawerContent.setTranslationX(drawerContainer.getWidth() * (1 - slideOffset));
                mainContent.setTranslationX(drawerContainer.getWidth() * slideOffset);
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `DrawerLayout` restores the drawer opened/closed state during `Activity` re-creation, so you might need to account for that, for example, during orientation changes, etc.

Comment: No sweat. This one was fun. Cheers!