# android slide menu right left

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, android-sliding

I try to create slide menu Right To Left slide menu.i searched custom slide menu and i found source,but this source is slide menu left to right
this is a source

```
public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int SLIDING_DURATION = 500;
    private static final int QUERY_INTERVAL = 16;
    int mainLayoutWidth;
    private View menu;
    private View content;
    private static int menuRightMargin = 5;

    private enum MenuState {
        HIDING, HIDDEN, SHOWING, SHOWN,
    };

    private int contentXOffset;
    private MenuState currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
    private Scroller menuScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
            new EaseInInterpolator());
    private Runnable menuRunnable = new MenuRunnable();
    private Handler menuHandler = new Handler();
    int prevX = 0;
    boolean isDragging = false;
    int lastDiffX = 0;

    public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MainLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        menuRightMargin = mainLayoutWidth * 60 / 100;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        menu = this.getChildAt(0);
        content = this.getChildAt(1);
        content.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return MainLayout.this.onContentTouch(v, event);
            }
        });
        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        if (changed) {
            LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) content
                    .getLayoutParams();
            contentLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            contentLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth();
            LayoutParams menuLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) menu
                    .getLayoutParams();
            menuLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            menuLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth() - menuRightMargin;
        }
        menu.layout(left, top, right - menuRightMargin, bottom);
        content.layout(left + contentXOffset, top, right + contentXOffset,
                bottom);

    }

    public void toggleMenu() {

        if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
                || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
            return;

        switch (currentMenuState) {
        case HIDDEN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            menuScroller.startScroll(0, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;
        case SHOWN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
            menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    protected class MenuRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean isScrolling = menuScroller.computeScrollOffset();
            adjustContentPosition(isScrolling);
        }
    }

    private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isScrolling) {
        int scrollerXOffset = menuScroller.getCurrX();

        content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerXOffset - contentXOffset);

        contentXOffset = scrollerXOffset;
        this.invalidate();
        if (isScrolling)
            menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
        else
            this.onMenuSlidingComplete();
    }

    private void onMenuSlidingComplete() {
        switch (currentMenuState) {
        case SHOWING:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWN;
            break;
        case HIDING:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
            menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
    }

    protected class EaseInInterpolator implements Interpolator {
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float t) {
            return (float) Math.pow(t - 1, 5) + 1;
        }

    }

    public boolean isMenuShown() {
        return currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWN;
    }

    public boolean onContentTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
                || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
            return false;
        int curX = (int) event.getRawX();
        int diffX = 0;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            prevX = curX;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!isDragging) {
                isDragging = true;
                menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            diffX = curX - prevX;
            if (contentXOffset + diffX <= 0) {
                diffX = -contentXOffset;
            } else if (contentXOffset + diffX > mainLayoutWidth
                    - menuRightMargin) {
                diffX = mainLayoutWidth + menuRightMargin + contentXOffset;
            }
            content.offsetLeftAndRight(diffX);
            contentXOffset += diffX;
            this.invalidate();

            prevX = curX;
            lastDiffX = diffX;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up lastDiffX "
                    + lastDiffX);

            if (lastDiffX > 0) {
                currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
                menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0,
                        menu.getLayoutParams().width - contentXOffset, 0,
                        SLIDING_DURATION);
            } else if (lastDiffX < 0) {
                currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
                menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 0,
                        SLIDING_DURATION);
            }
            menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
            this.invalidate();
            isDragging = false;
            prevX = 0;
            lastDiffX = 0;
            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

this code working perfec.i can create slide menu,but now i want to rewrite this code.i want to recieve slide menu right to left.i want swap this example.
p.s i know same good examples about slide menu but i want to rewrite this source.
how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me.thanks everyone

Comment: Are you just trying to create a Navigation drawer? You can just use a [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) and get a fully working slide in menu with just a few lines of code.

Comment: @drschultz thank you i know   DrawerLayout but i don't need it because  i want to move frame layout in right to left like this http://alexanderblom.se/images/facebook-ios.jpeg

Comment: Ah! Ok, so you want your content to slide, revealing the menu below? Take a look at this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587371/android-move-main-content-to-reveal-drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587371/android-move-main-content-to-reveal-drawer)

Comment: wow this is a perfect but my drawerlayout is right side how i can rewrite this code ?   drawerContent.setX(drawerView.getWidth() * (1 - slideOffset));
                mainContent.setX(drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset); @ drschultz

Comment: @drschultz check my  comment

Comment: Too much to explain in a comment. See my answer below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To have your main content slide, revealing a menu underneath, there is a nice example on how to do that here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587371/android-move-main-content-to-reveal‌​-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587371/android-move-main-content-to-reveal%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-drawer)

Since you want your menu to be revealed on the right side, you would just subtract the X calculations from the width of the parent view, which in the example is a `DrawerLayout` called `drawerLayout`. So you would make the following adjustments to these lines:

This is the original code for setting the X position of the drawer and content:

```
drawerContent.setX(drawerView.getWidth() * (1 - slideOffset));
mainContent.setX(drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);
```

Those calculations start the slide at position 0, and slide the content as far as the width of the drawer. Instead, we want a starting position of the width of the parent layout (our `drawerLayout` view), and slide back toward zero (as far as the width of the drawer). So we would change those lines to this:

```
drawerContent.setX(drawerLayout.getWidth() - (drawerView.getWidth() * (1 - slideOffset)));
mainContent.setX(drawerLayout.getWidth() - (drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset));
```

Comment: thank you your answer,but your second code not working perfect,when i have drawerlayout right side