# Android: How to create a navigation drawer with custom layout

Tags: android, slidingmenu, navigation-drawer, android-sliding, sliding-window

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer like this:

[facebook side chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO1KH.png)

inside the navigation drawer,I need a login page instead of a list,like this:

[side login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cEp9.png)

I didn't find any helpful libraries for doing this (SlidingMenu was the library nearest to the solution) and I found just side menu with a list of elements.
Could you please suggest me a solution/library to use?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement by overriding drawer slide listener. Here it is well explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588398/4804264

Comment: I spent two hours trying to understand the example but I didn't get completely, because the code has missing parts and I cannot check, do you have maybe a complete (similar) example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom Viewgroup to control the View(your side menu).
And using the ValueAnimator, you can slide the menu from the side.

[Custom components](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

[Custom](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-custom-layout-in-android-by-extending-viewgroup-class)

[Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)