# How to Make Static Navigation Android Tablet? like this design

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

Hi I'm having trouble on making layout like this design because the navigation bar is difficult to make it become functional.

[this is the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QE7j.png)

I have created the class like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation)

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    
}

private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_user -> {
                val fragment = UserFragment()
                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_scaner -> {
                val fragment = ScannerFragment()
                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_laporan -> {
                val fragment = LaporanFragment()

                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notif ->{
                val fragment = NotificationFragment()

                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_chat -> {
                val fragment = LaporanFragment()

                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                val fragment = LaporanFragment()

                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }


        }
        false
    }

private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) = supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.design_bottom_sheet_slide_in, R.anim.design_bottom_sheet_slide_out)
    .replace(R.id.content, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
    .commit()
}
```

and this is my layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:background="#FAFAFC"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearnama"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"

    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/foto_profil_operator"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/lisa" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Nama Operator" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearnama"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MENU"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pp2k"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation">

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp2k"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="navigation"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >


        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried several navigation listener such as `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)`
But it won't work. Maybe someone know how I can solve my problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean moving the "main content" of your app to the right upon opening the nav drawer? If yes, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057084/how-to-move-main-content-with-drawer-layout-left-side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587371/moving-the-main-content-to-reveal-a-drawer/33588398#33588398

Comment: This one I used once and it is working perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335300/moving-and-resizing-drawerlayouts-content-on-sliding/37336064#37336064