# How to move content to right side in a DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

When I click the toggle button, there will be a menu in right side

[image]

Comment: It is answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311247/3101777

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you please try using the following attribute

```
android:layout_gravity = "end"
```

in your NavigationView? Please place this attribute in your NavigationView and check.