# How to keep my navigation drawer always below my content?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in my App. When I open the drawer I want it to open below the content, I changed some attributes to get the image [what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjw3m.png). but what I want is show in image [What I want to reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am360.png), and you can find my code here:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final CoordinatorLayout content = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        private float scaleFactor = 6f;//  private float scaleFactor = 6f;


        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

            float slideX = drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset;
            content.setTranslationX(slideX);

           content.setScaleX(1 );
           content.setScaleY(1 - (slideOffset / scaleFactor));
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerElevation(0f);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move main content with Drawer Layout left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057084/how-to-move-main-content-with-drawer-layout-left-side)

Comment: that not what i want , it doesn t work for me ,i want to open my drawer full screen and my Layout content on the top  like the image two ,any help

Comment: Still facing a problem or solved it?

Comment: still the same problem